# How to get the color of an element which i have clicked or its background color via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to use `EyeDropper` API but I think there are some issues on Linux because it requires me to share my screen and Although I shared, I could not get a result. I'm getting this after clicking the button. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LIdW.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>COLOR PICKER</title>

    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Sharp:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
    />
    <!-- CSS & SCRIPT -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="grid pi-cent">
    <div class="container flex-col">
      <header class="flex jc-cnt ai-cnt">
        <button class="pick-btn">Pick Color</button>
      </header>
      <article class="flex jc-sb">
        <p>Picked Color<s class="plural">s</s></p>
        <a href="">Clear All</a>
      </article>
      <ul class="grid">
        <li class="flex">
          <div
            class="color"
            style="--bg: #000000; width: 15px; height: 15px"
          ></div>
          <p class="clr-code">#0000</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
      const pickBtn = document.querySelector(".pick-btn");

      const pickColor = async (e) => {
        try {
          const eDrop = new window.EyeDropper();
          const resp = await eDrop.open();
          console.log(resp);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      pickBtn.addEventListener("click", pickColor);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: EyeDropper API is still in an experimental API. Is it definitely fully supported on the browser you're trying? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper_API#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `click` event to the button.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!window.EyeDropper) {
    resultElement.textContent = 'Your browser does not support the EyeDropper API';
    return;
  }

  const eyeDropper = new EyeDropper();

  eyeDropper.open().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.sRGBHex);
  }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
  });
})
```

```css
.green,
.blue,
.red {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="green">Green color</div>
<div class="blue">Blue color</div>
<div class="red">Red color</div>


<button>Pick color</button>
```

**As @ourmaninamsterdam mentioned the EyeDropper is experimental and only supported in chromium browsers like edge, chrome, opera**

[Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EyeDropper#browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thank you that's the answer but it wasn't like an eye dropper. maybe in the future, i may be able to find another alternative to EyeDropper API. And also getPropertyValue() should be used beside getComputedStyle()...

Comment: @KemalTuzer, sorry, I just update the answer with `EyeDropper` API.